# i want to use speech recognition library in python. it needs flac but i can not install it

Tags: python

i downloaded windows flac from [flac website](https://xiph.org/flac/download.html) and tried to run flac.exe

it seems after installation it should been a folder named flac in C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program Files directory but it`s not.

this is my error : OSError: FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent.

if you have another solution for convert speech to text please tell me.

can anybody help me???

Answer (score 0):

you can use pyaudio also simply do a apt-get install pyaudio.

Comment: OP is in a Windows system. Are you suggesting to use Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: pyaudio does not convert voice to text